# White screen after migrating site, but wp-admin works fine. Disabling all plugins, applying default theme and enabling debug mode does nothing

Tags: php, errors, migration

I migrated my wordpress site from a very old host with these steps:

- Downloaded the site to local desktop
- Downloaded database (php 5.5)
- Created new database in myphp (php 7.4) and edited exported database to reflect new database name.
- Imported database (I had to remove the "create database" operation at the start before it let me do this)
- Put html wordpress files into public_html directory
- Edited wp-config to with new database information

The back end works as it should. However, the main site is a white page. I have attempted the following so far

- Disable plugins - no change
- Change to default theme - no change (plugins or no plugins)
- Increased memory limit in wp-config - no change
- Deleted old .htaccess file - no change
- Added the below code - doesn't show errors on front page, does not generate error log file in wp-content folder

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- I did find an error.log file in public_html with the following:

```
[07-Sep-2021 06:26:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $tasks_meta_id in /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#1 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(518): WP_Hook->do_action()
#2 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/actions/ActionScheduler_Action.php(22): do_action_ref_array()
#3 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/abstracts/ActionScheduler_Abstract_QueueRunner.php(65): ActionScheduler_Action->execute()
#4 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(162): ActionScheduler_Abstract_QueueRunner->process_action()
#5 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/vendor/woocommerce/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(132): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->do_batch()
#6 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->run()
#7 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(518): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /home/XXXXXXX/public_html/wp-cron.php(138): do_action_ref_array()
#10 {main}
  thrown in /home/XXXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 303
```

It says the error is potentially with the "actionscheduler" component of "woocommerce", which I never had installed, but I guess it could be in the theme I'm using. However, I never had this issue on the old site. I googled around and read in [another thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-on-update-to-1-5-9-5-from-1-5-8-2/) that installing the action scheduler plugin can fix this, but it didn't work either.

Seems like I can't get anything except a blank white screen on my site.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your case `actionscheduler` is being used by `wpforms-lite`. Have you deactivated that plugin? It's possible that the plugin is using a version of actionscheduler that's not compatible with your new host. You should contact its developers for support.

Comment: I tried disabling/deleting (renaming in plugins folder) it and it doesn't help. The plugin is not essential to the site, wouldn't disabling it at least get past this error?

Comment: I don’t know exactly how actionscheduler works, but the error is related to wp-cron.php, so it may be trying to run tasks in a backlog that were added by the plugin. This is an issue with the plugin, so as I said already, you need to contact the plugin developers.